# php - quoted date is subtracting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I don't know why this is happening but I have already quoted my date and everytime I run this code, instead of updating dates, it's just subtracting them and returning:

**0000-00-00**

Here is my code:

```
$format_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
$newinfo = "UPDATE
                        tickets
                      SET
                        `date` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connct,$format_date)."'
                        AND `boolean` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connct,$booleancheck)."'
                      WHERE
                        `id` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connct,$id)."'
                     ";
$update_this = mysqli_query($connct, $newinfo);
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Barmar, I used `,`instead of `AND` and it worked.

```
$newinfo = "UPDATE
                        tickets
                      SET
                        `date` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connct,$formatar_data)."',
                        `boolean` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connct,$booleancheck)."'
                      WHERE
                        `id` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connct,$id)."'
                     ";
```

Comment: Separate columns being updated with `,` not `AND`.

Comment: Use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with such values.

Comment: Because of operator precedence, your query is equivalent to `SET date  = ('2018-04-21' AND boolean = '1')`

Comment: @Barmar thank you a lot, it's now working and I understood what I was doing wrong!